# C++: Are iostream operator<< and operator>>s for primitive types virtual?

Tags: c++, io, virtual, iostream, operator-keyword

As `ifstream` and `istringstream` are inherited from `istream`, I expected that `istream` (or rather, `basic_istream`) would declare `operator>>` for primitive types like this:

`virtual istream& istream::operator>>(char &c);
 virtual istream& istream::operator>>(int &i);`

A quick glance at the source suggests this is not the case -- these functions don't look to be virtual. Am I missing something?

[The context is that I am trying to roll istreams which perform binary I/O, correct for endianness, etc..]

Comment: short answer - they're not virtual but they work by calling other functions which are virtual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not virtual. There are some virtual functions inside the basic stream functionality, but that's inside the parts that input/output the actual data, not the formatting of types to strings, which is what actually happens in `operator>>`.

Edit: I believe all the virtual functionality is "hidden" from the public interfaces. `basic_streambuf::pubseekpos` is, at least in the gcc supplied headers as a call to a the virtual `seekpos`.

Comment: Are the "virtual functions inside the basic stream functionality" part of the public interface, or implementation-dependent?

Answer (score 2):

They are not virtual, but there are only overloads for `istream/ostream`, which all derived classes use. All `stream` classes use a buffer inside, which is [basic_streambuf or derived from it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf). `basic_streambuf` has many virtual functions, so it shouldn't be great problem to write your `stream` class in terms of `streambuf`.